# Subplots don't plot next to each other (Overleaf)

Tags: graphics, overleaf, subplot

I am trying to put two subplots next to eachother under one big subplot, with this code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.9\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures2/ROI1spec.jpg}
\caption{The averaged spectrum over ROI1}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures2/ROI2spec.jpg}
  \caption{The averaged spectrum over ROI2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures2/ROI3spec.jpg}
  \caption{The averaged spectrum over ROI3}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Yet the output looks like this:
[image: The output]

I have tried putting the two smaller subplot at the top and changing the width to .4, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the blank lines bewteen the two last ones. A blank line in latex generally means new paragraph so the images are in their own paragraphs.,

Comment: Additionally, next time, please post a full self contained example instead of a sniplet like this. A full but minimal self contained example ensures that others can copy and test your code as is. Here for example the code is not self contained as we don't have the images (you can replace them with `\rule{width}{height}`